# Python - Pandas - Reading excel file from o365

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read an o365 excel file into a pandas dataframe for analysis. I'm able to connect and authenticate, however am getting the error: "Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n<!DOCT' "

Some googling of the error showed that this can be an encoding issue, or that xlrd is misinterpreting the file as being encrypted. However, none of the solutions I found apply to my exact scenario, trying to read from o365 into pandas.

I know this is possible, does anybody see anything inherently wrong with my method of reading the spreadsheet?

Code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import io
from xlrd import *
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://somedomain.somesite.com/:x:/r/sites/IT/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?e=4%3Ay8lZaY&at=9&CID=0CEFB96F-C585-4B93-95D8-7B9161922C05&wdLOR=c2549E09D-B403-4600-9D64-4E3AFD70A2D3&share=EbCMUuWuEsRJpPItV4SAhHQBum7Fe0ISfki4Na-k0VIlsA'
username = 'dummy@account.com'
password = 'fakepw'

def pullO365():
    ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
    if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
        ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
        web = ctx.web
        ctx.load(web)
        ctx.execute_query()
        print("O365 authentication successful")
    else:
        print("O365 authentication failed.")
    
    response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)

    #save data to BytesIO stream
    bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
    bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

    #read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe 
    normResults = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name=None, usecols="H,G,I,J,F")

    df = pd.DataFrame(normResults)

    return df
```

Comment: few things can be tried as limitations to reproduce this. if you just save the excel, can you open it using excel? 2nd - look at traceback error, if can determine the engine it used, or try giving engine explicitly. somehow I feel that `bytes_file_obj` is not really an excel type.

Comment: your error shows `<!DOCT` which can be `<!DOCTYPE html>` and it means you get HTML instead of expected file. You should get this HTML and display to check if there are information which can explain what can be the problem.

Comment: @boog were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @pdangelo4 unfortunately I never did. something about how o365 encodes the .xlsx file causing the "BOF" error... though I know of people who have used the library successfully, I ended up using MS "power automate" to automate the process of exporting the o365 spreadsheet to csv, and just imported the csv into pandas which works just fine. Obviously not as clean/streamlined as importing directly from o365...

Comment: @boog, I figured it out let me answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Don't fill spaces with special characters for your folder names.

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

authcookie = Office365('https://<organization>.sharepoint.com/', username='<your username>', password='<your pw>').GetCookies()
site = Site('https://<organization>.sharepoint.com/teams/<team name>', version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)
#version=Version.v2016, 
folder = site.Folder('Shared Documents/<Folder>/<Subfolder>/<Subfolder>')
file = folder.get_file('xxxxx.csv')
with open("xxxxx.csv", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(file)
print('---')
folder.upload_file('xlsx', 'xxxxx.xlsx')
```

Comment: What if the remote file is enforced with 2FA? How to deal with two-way authentication to read a remote shared Excel file?